# Infinispan TreeCache not getting distributed properly

Tags: infinispan

I'm using WildFly 8.2 with infinispan 6. I'm having distribution issue in Infinispan TreeCache. Populated Tree structure as follows,

- /parent/child1/(k1,v1)
- /parent/child1/(k2,v2)
- ..
- ..
- /parent/child1/(kN,vN)

In Two Nodes environment with Owner one for TreeCache, cannot read these Key values in first node. But Able to get value in Second Node. I'm not sure, why not able to read the value, even both nodes are clustered.

If i supposed to convert cache as replicated cache, things are working properly. Problem comes in two nodes with single owner. (For example i said single owner.  Problem is same, even it's 4 nodes with 2 owners)

I would appreciate your help...

Thanks.

Comment: Tree cache module was meant as a migration path for those users coming from JBoss Cache, I'd suggest you try using the main EmbeddedCache interface which extends ConcurrentMap instead.

Comment: @GalderZamarreño Thanks for the reply. In our application, set of key values under child1 will be changing in runtime. Then will remove child1, so that set of key values will be removed and new set will get loaded in Cache. But with EmbeddedCache, set of key values should be removed looping through it. I'm not sure about exact key. it depends on "child1". key can be used as child1#keyN, child2#KeyN. But while removing those, i should check starts with "child1", then remove. It seems complicated. Your suggestion will help. Thanks.

Comment: @GalderZamarreño, if the TreeCache module is not maintained, why isn't it marked as Deprecated? That way developers don't start using the TreeCache module, only to find that they need to reimplement when they hit bugs with it and find that it's unmaintained.

Comment: You could get a stream of keys, e.g. keySet().stream(), then filter and remove keys that match the pattern. Another way would be for parent key to keep track of child keys manually. Yet another option would be to do more complex queries on keys using extensions provided by the Query module.

Comment: In terms of deprecating the tree module, you have a point. I've emailed the infinispan-dev list to discuss this in more detail.